# Twisted Conch for Python 2.71 on Windows Server 2008 R2 x64?

Tags: twisted, windows-server-2008-r2, python-2.7, pycrypto

I'm planning on using Twisted Conch for the SFTP protion of an application I'm working on. The rest of the application is built on Python 2.71, and while it appears that Twisted as a whole is available for Python 2.7, the Download page at http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/wiki/Downloads would appear to show that only Python 2.5 is supported by Conch, because it depends on PyCrypto 2.0.1.

Is this the case, or is there a build of Conch for Python 2.7 out there somewhere?

This is on a Windows Server 2006 R2 x64 box, for what its worth.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Google turns up http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/modules.shtml#pycrypto

Comment: I found that as well, unfortunately, only 32bit PyCrypto is provided there. I can build my entire application on 32bit if I need to, but would prefer to use 64bit.

Comment: Ah, 64bit, right.  Dunno then.  http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/ is another good resource, but PyCrypto is not available for "legal or technical" reasons.  Might be worth pinging that guy to see if there's anything to be done to resolve that.  http://www.enthought.com/products/getepd.php might be another option.

Answer (score 1):

for windows x64 here is workaround 
[Compiling Python 2.7 Modules](http://blog.victorjabur.com/2011/06/05/compiling-python-2-7-modules-on-windows-32-and-64-using-msvc-2008-express/). Although it looks like a big task I managed to compile and build pycrypto2.4.1 for win64.